# Second 4K monitor intermittently identified as a 1440p monitor

Tags: macos, display, 4k

I have two identical 4K monitors that I have connected via USB C to a CalDigit Thunderbolt 4 mini dock.

Over the last year or so, around 30-40% of the time I've noticed that upon plugging in my M1 Pro MacBook Pro to my dock, the second monitor gets incorrectly identified as a 1440p monitor. Here is the main monitor which is always identified correctly:

[image]

And here is the misidentified monitor:

[image]

What is the reason for the intermittent monitor misidentification? Is it macOS, or something to do with my "one cable" setup? How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried plugging both monitors directly into the Mac, bypassing the dock? That would be my first troubleshooting step...

Comment: That would probably work. But it's not really something I'm interested in doing all the time. After all, I paid an extra for the premium of having Thunderbolt 3/4 on my MacBook. I've noticed this behavior across multiple Thunderbolt 4 docks

Comment: As a **troubleshooting** step it is something to do to find out if the issue is with the Mac or the cables/adapters/dock. Not a permanent fix.